# Export 2 different HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default Component; //work well
export const one = oneHOC(Component); //not work
export const two = twoHOC(Component); // not work
```

How to import HOC in different file in curly brackets? Something like:

```
import {one, two} from "path/to/component"
```

Comment: What do you see when it's not working?

Comment: Render method isn't fire. So I don't see anything :) HOC working properly when I am trying export default oneHOC(Component)

Comment: Sorry, I meant: what is the error that you see? Because right now it seems like everything is supposed to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be capitalization -- sometimes react [requires your components to be uppercase](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4695). Try this:

```
export default Component; //work well
export const One = oneHOC(Component); //not work
export const Two = twoHOC(Component); // not work
```

--

```
import {One, Two} from "path/to/component"
```

Comment: Silly me :) Thank You